# Why is Koin scoping feature not working properly?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, koin, koin-scope

So **scoping with Koin DI seem to throw a weird exception** when KoinApplication::checkModules() method is called within a unit test. Here is the full code:

```
import org.koin.core.KoinApplication
import org.koin.core.component.KoinComponent
import org.koin.core.component.KoinScopeComponent
import org.koin.core.component.createScope
import org.koin.core.component.inject
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
import org.koin.core.logger.Level
import org.koin.core.scope.Scope
import org.koin.dsl.module
import org.koin.test.KoinTest
import org.koin.test.check.checkModules
import org.koin.test.inject
import kotlin.test.BeforeTest
import kotlin.test.Test

class FixScopingTest : KoinTest {

    private val component1: Component1 by inject()

    private lateinit var koinApp: KoinApplication

    @BeforeTest
    fun setup() {
        koinApp = startKoin {
            modules(
                module {
                    single { Component1() }
                    scope<Component1> {
                        scoped { Component2() }
                    }
                }
            )
            // printLogger(Level.DEBUG)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun verifyKoinApp() {
        //component1.component2.print()
        koinApp.checkModules()
    }
}

class Component1 : KoinComponent, KoinScopeComponent {
    override val scope: Scope by lazy { createScope(this) }
    val component2: Component2 by inject()
}

class Component2 {
    fun print() = println("Component2::print()")
}
```

**exception 1:**

```
com.xycompany.xyproj.xypackage.FixScopingTest > verifyKoinApp FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing MockProvider. Please use MockProvider.register() to register a new mock provider
        at org.koin.test.mock.MockProvider.getProvider(MockProvider.kt:10)
        at org.koin.test.mock.MockProvider.makeMock(MockProvider.kt:23)
        at org.koin.test.check.CheckModulesKt.mockSourceValue(CheckModules.kt:102)
        at org.koin.test.check.CheckModulesKt.check(CheckModules.kt:95)
        at org.koin.test.check.CheckModulesKt.checkAllDefinitions(CheckModules.kt:86)
        at org.koin.test.check.CheckModulesKt.checkModules(CheckModules.kt:72)
        at org.koin.test.check.CheckModulesKt.checkModules(CheckModules.kt:40)
        at org.koin.test.check.CheckModulesKt.checkModules$default(CheckModules.kt:40)
        at com.xycompany.xyproj.xypackage.FixScopingTest.verifyKoinApp(FixScopingTest.kt:43)
```

**Second weird issue** appears when you uncomment the commented part so we would have usage of scoped components on DEBBUG level logger:

**exception 2:**

```
com.xycompany.xyproj.xypackage.FixScopingTest > verifyKoinApp FAILED
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'double kotlin.time.Duration.toDouble-impl(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)'
        at org.koin.core.time.MeasureKt.measureDurationForResult(Measure.kt:41)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:189)
        at com.xycompany.xyproj.xypackage.FixScopingTest$special$$inlined$inject$default$1.invoke(KoinTest.kt:53)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at com.xycompany.xyproj.xypackage.FixScopingTest.getComponent1(FixScopingTest.kt:20)
        at com.xycompany.xyproj.xypackage.FixScopingTest.verifyKoinApp(FixScopingTest.kt:41)
```

SETTINGS:
Kotlin Multiplatform Project (test is run in both Andorid and Common packages with the same problem)

VERSIONS:
koin-core: `3.1.3`
koin-android: `3.1.3`

Comment: Umm... so where is your `MockProviderRule`? You have looked over [this link](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-test/testing/) right? [This issue seems to be fixed back in 3.0.1](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/1057)

Comment: It seems that KMM/KMP koin injection is slightly different, so be sure to take a look at [this](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-mp/kmp) too.  Look through both things and pay attention to the TestRules they're using since you don't seem to be using any of that. Perhaps it resolves your issue.

Comment: @Shark I don't have mocks so `MockProviderRule` is not required and `KoinTestRule` per docs doesn't do anything as it is only used to create a Koin applicaiton with a local context which doesn't solve anything for me here :/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add a `MockProviderRule` when using `scoped`. It's not required if are not using scopes.

```
@get:Rule
val mockProvider = MockProviderRule.create { clazz ->
    // Mock with your framework here given clazz 
    // e.g: Mockito.mock(clazz.java)
}
```

And for it to work you also need to add this dependency to gradle

```
testImplementation "io.insert-koin:koin-test-junit4:3.1.6"
```

https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-test/checkmodules/#allow-mocking-with-a-junit-rule